# Do we get production.log file while running in product mode from local in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

1. While working on local / development mode, we will get the development.log file under log folder. Do we get the production.log while running in the production mode?
2. If yes, when I `run RAILS_ENV=production rails s`, is the production.log is similar to that we run on any AWS/ Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, we have `production.log` while running in the production mode.
2. Yes, it is the same.

To add to how you might want to configure your production log in the production environment

If you are using heroku

```
heroku logs --tail
```

If you are using a VPS. you might want to use this approach by using the rsyslog as a buffer, else it would block the rails server and slow down the rails server.

Add the following line to `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`

```
gem 'remote_syslog_logger'
```

In `/etc/rsyslog.conf` configure the syslog daemon to accept information pulled

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
```

Add the following line to `config/environments/production.rb`.

```
config.logger = RemoteSyslogLogger.new('<host>.papertrailapp.com', XXXXX)
```

Finally, restart the rsyslog daemon

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```